# "Desde un principio" en lugar de "desde el principio"

Tags: gramática, selección-de-palabras, portugués

El Chapúlin Colorado dice en su lengua madre: *¡Lo sospeché desde un principio!*

Mientras en el dobraje brasileño dice: *Suspeitei desde o princípio!*

Esa es una diferencia entre el castellano y el portugués. Se puede decir en su idioma "desde un principio" en lugar de "desde el principio", pero la única forma posible en portugués sería: "desde o princípio". Para nosotros, "um princípio" solo tendría sentido en frases como "um princípio de incêndio".

Hay registros de cómo surgió "desde un principio"? Como el principio de algo es siempre uno y, al decir "desde o princípio", imagino "desde o princípio desta história", esta fue una sorpresa gramatical para mí.

Comment: "Desde un principio" se oye más dramático, más tajante, en el uso que ejemplificaste.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ambas formas, *desde un principio* y *desde el principio*, existen y son correctas en español. Son muy similares, si no idénticas, en significado.(*)

En cuanto a su uso, sólo "desde el principio" podrá utilizarse si existe un posmodificador, como en *desde **el** principio **de la historia***.

En español, sólo existe la obligación de usar "un" o "el" con otras preposiciones, por ejemplo:

- en **un** principio (NO *en **el** principio*): también *en un comienzo*
- a**l** principio (NO *a **un** principio*): también *al inicio, al comienzo*

En portugués, en ambos casos se utiliza el artículo definido: *n**o** início, n**o** começo*.

Cuando "principio" tiene un sentido lógico, no temporal, no se utiliza artículo:

- *En principio*, ambas formas son correctas.

En cuanto al origen de "desde un principio", parece haber registrado un tímido comienzo para luego estabilizarse en el uso:

[image: principio]

(*) Nota: En todos los casos en que utiliza el artículo indefinido, el principio, inicio o comienzo no remite a ningún período, mientras que el artículo definido podría implicar que se está haciendo referencia al principio, inicio o comienzo de una determinada etapa.